# jQuery selector unintelligible issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

**[I have following example](http://jsfiddle.net/MrTest/xcEnS/)**

What it should do:

- check is there `.box-wrapper` in the doc
- if yes and there is an click event on `.tabs li a`
- find `.selected` and set class to empty string
- find parent of `this` - clicked link and add `.selected`

And in the last step it is failing as you can see.
`console.log( $('this').parent('li') ); = []`

**Why? What is wrong? Any suggestion much appreciated.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`this` is an DOM object, not a selector string, so you need:

```
$(this).parent('li').addClass('selected');
console.log($(this).parent('li'));
```

instead of:

```
$('this').parent('li').addClass('selected');
console.log($('this').parent('li'));
```

`$('this')` will cause jQuery to construct an object which wraps all elements matching your selector. 'this' is not a valid selector, so you get that 'selector unintelligible' error, whereas `$(this)` refers to the jQuery-wrapped clicked anchor.

Comment: Ohhh.. I knew that:P Coffe > Sleep. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

not sure what box wrapper has to do with it but this click function should work:

```
$(".tabs li a").click(function(){
     $(".tabs li").removeClass("selected");
     $(this).parent().addClass("selected");
}
```

Comment: this bit of code is part of something bigger. Sorry for the confusion.